# Explanation of how OpenGL manages its transformation matrices

Tags: python, opengl, glm-math, opengl-compat

I'm programming in Python with the PyOpenGL module. I started working on a camera module for view field manipulation, but I'm stuck with the gluLookAt() function. My problem is that when I push a key to translate the camera, it works fine but doesn't stop when I release the key. I think it might be because I have to reinitialize the transformation matrix or something. I've seen that I'm supposed to push and pop matrices, or load the identity matrix somewhere, but right now I'm very confused as to what OpenGL does exactly with the matrix that I assume gluLookAt() gives it.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy as np
import glm
from math import * 
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

class camera:
    def __init__(self, position, angles, target):
        self.position = glm.vec3(position[0], position[1], position[2])
        self.front = glm.normalize(self.position - glm.vec3(target[0], target[1], target[2]))
        self.upVector = glm.normalize(glm.cross(self.front, glm.normalize(glm.cross(self.front, glm.vec3(0, 1, 0)))))
    def update(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        gluLookAt(self.position[0], self.position[1], self.position[2], self.position[0] + self.front[0],
        self.position[1] + self.front[1], self.position[2] + self.front[2], self.upVector[0], self.upVector[1], self.upVector[2])        

    def getPos(self):
        return self.position

    def translateCamera(self, vector):
        self.position = self.position + vector

    def keyboardControl(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LALT] and keys[K_F4]:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if keys[K_w] and not isSprinting:
            self.position += self.front * 0.02085
        if keys[K_s]:
            self.position -= self.front * 0.02085
        if keys[K_d]:
            self.position += glm.normalize(glm.cross(self.front, self.upVector)) * 0.02085
        if keys[K_a]:
            self.position -= glm.normalize(glm.cross(self.front, self.upVector)) * 0.02085
```

The camera keeps coasting when I let go of the key, and I think maybe since I don't reset a matrix somewhere, it just keeps applying the matrix given by gluLookAt() over and over again.

I also tried something with GLM, and managed to create the transformation matrix I wanted with glm.lookAt(), but I don't know how to pass it on so OpenGL processes it.

How should I use glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix?  And when do I have to use glLoadIdentity?

Comment: From the error you report, it is more likely, that you do not handle your key events correctly. The continuous movement is caused by a continuous change in the matrices and vectors you use. Print something like "key pressed" and "key released" every time you push and release a button. Then report back.

Answer (score 0):

> The camera keeps coasting when I let go of the key, and I think maybe since I don't reset a matrix somewhere, it just keeps applying the matrix given by `gluLookAt()` over and over again.

[`gluLookAt`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) does not just set a matrix, if defines a matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix.
Note all the matrix operations like [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml),  [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml), [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) etc. multiply a matrix to the current matrix.

Load the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix), by [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml), before `gluLookAt`:

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
gluLookAt(
    self.position[0], self.position[1], self.position[2],
    self.position[0] + self.front[0], self.position[1] + self.front[1], self.position[2] + self.front[2], 
    self.upVector[0], self.upVector[1], self.upVector[2])
```

---

I also tried something with GLM, and managed to create the transformation matrix I wanted with `glm.lookAt()`, but I don't know how to pass it on so OpenGL processes it.

Use [`glLoadMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml) and `glm.value_ptr` to load a matrix:

```py
viewMatrix = glm.lookAt(self.position, self.position + self.front, self.upVector)
vieMatList = [viewMatrix[i][j] for i in range(4) for j in range(4)]
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadMatrixf(vieMatList)
```

Note a matrix can be multiplied to the current matrix by [`glMultMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml).

Comment: I tried both suggestions. The one using gluLookAt worked somewhat, with a problem being that the scene is now 2-dimensional (I am using cubes to debug, and it renders only one of the faces between certain z-values), but I think that is another problem and is not related to this issue. For the one using GLM, it returns me an AttributeError. Also, should I use glLoadMatrixf() or glLoadMatrixd()?

Comment: The scene is not 2 dimensional it seems to be 2 dimensional. That's related to the point of view and [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). Anyway, to explain all that is to broad for an answer. There a lot of good tutorials, I recommend to read [LearnOpenGL - Camera/View space](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera). Yes I know the language of the tutorial is C++. [OpenGL with PyOpenGL introduction](https://pythonprogramming.net/opengl-rotating-cube-example-pyopengl-tutorial/) seems to be a good tutorial, too.